# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor not working in REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a rest api endpoint that is of type "String". Inside the endpoint method's body, I implemented a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor object that runs every 20 minutes to write to a database. However, when I deploy the api and run the endpoint, even though the endpoint returns the String it's supposed to, the database NEVER gets populated. I ran the exact same ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor code in a simple java program and it writes to the database perfectly, so I know it can't be because of the scheduling code. Does anyone know what may be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Please give more specific details to your problem (i.e code samples and outputs). This will make it possible to help solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should hold a reference to the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor object in a static field of your resource class. Then start the timer in the constructor of your resource class. Note that your resource class should be a Singleton which is annotated with @Singleton annotation. Otherwise timer will reset every time you receive a request from a client.